# What mechanisms require the use of different polarities in DC welding?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

In gas metal arc welding, an electric arc forms between the work piece and a consumable wire, heating the work piece and also melting the tip of this consumable wire, which is continually fed into the weld.

I recently found out that it is important to use the correct polarity when welding with direct current. Some electrode (i.e. the consumable wire) materials require that the electrode be positive and others that it be negative. Welding machines come with special mechanisms for reversing the polarity as necessary.

Searching for why this would be the case explains, at best, that this determines whether the work piece or the wire gets the most heat. Having always perceived any such heating as entirely symmetric under polarity reversal, this puzzles me.

Welding tutorials highlight the importance of polarity, as do the instructions on the welding wire and the machines themselves. What are the mechanisms that affect the weld depending on the polarity used?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with heating, but more about trying to repell certain ions in the gas from the piece being welded.  Just a guess though.

Comment: My suspicion is that the majority of heating occurs when high-energy electrons (going from negative to positive voltage surfaces) hit the +V surface and transfer their energy to said surface.